# Xaml - radiobutton tag as image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button

I need to set custom image instead of SymbolIcon as `RadioButton Tag` property, so far tried:

```
Home.Tag = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/my_asset.png"));
```

Where `Home` is name of my radiobutton;

Dosen't work, could somebody help?

Comment: Have you tried `BitmapIcon`?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Is it a compile error, is the resulting output not what you expected, etc.?

Comment: @moswald it dosen't crash, just that image isn't displayed there is empty space, i'm using radio buttons in SplitView and need to set this image to tag property so it's displayed while SpliView isn't expanded.

Comment: @MikeEason Yeah tried it dosen't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var b = new BitmapImage();
b.BeginInit();
b.UriSource = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/my_asset.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
b.EndInit();
Home.Tag = b;
```

Comment: i seem unable to find methods "BeginInit" olso it's still assigning bitmapimage that dosen't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

To set an image within a radio button instead of using the content tag set up your XAML as follows:-

```
                    <StackPanel x:Name="rbMode2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbDrive1" Tag="Drive" IsChecked="true" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                GroupName="ShowSaveRoute" Tapped="RadioRouteMode_Tapped">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///images/Car.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbWalk1" Tag="Walk" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                GroupName="ShowSaveRoute" Tapped="RadioRouteMode_Tapped">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///images/Walking.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbFly1" Tag="Fly" Margin="5,0,0,0"  
                                GroupName="ShowSaveRoute" Tapped="RadioRouteMode_Tapped">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///images/Airplane.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
```

Images held in Projects image folder